# What to do with follow-ups to my comment to my own question?

Tags: feature-request

I had a longish follow-up (with Latex code) to a comment I had posted for my own question. It wouldn't fit in the space for a comment, and it seems you can't put Latex code in comments. It wasn't exactly an answer to my question, so I posted it as new "question." But it was closed for not being too vague and not a real question even though I stated it was a follow-up to my previous question, thus cutting off any possibility of a reply! What to do? Maybe you should expand the capabilities for the Comment box.

Comment: Also, you can put LaTeX code in comments - for example,
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}=\sqrt{\pi}$$

Answer (score 9):

If it's too long for a comment, either edit it into your question or take it to chat. The comment box is a necessary evil and expanding it would distract from the main purpose of the site (this is exactly why chat was created).